# Selecting the MFFC of a node

Tags: yosys

I need to determine the maximum fanout-free cone (MFFC) of nodes/cells in a circuit. As far as I am aware, there is no direct command in Yosys to do that. I thought it might be possible with the `select` command, but I have not figured out a correct sequence so far. My approach was to first select the fanin cone of a node/cell, and then try to remove those nodes with fanout that leaves the cone.

Is the `select` command of good use here, or is it easier to write a new pass to determine the MFFC?

Thanks and best regards

lwitsche

Comment: Although the select syntax is pretty powerful, I think a custom pass is going to be easiest. You might be able to reuse some code from the `flowmap` pass as that uses MFFCs internally.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I had the same idea and already looked at the ```flowmap``` code, and it might be a good starting point. Meanwhile, I have also figured out a sequence of ```select``` commands to select the MFFC. At this point, I do not need the most performant code, but just a quick solution to conduct some tests. Therefore, the ```select``` solution is sufficient for me right now. Later I might need to implement it to improve performance.